# Can I create a web part with a rich text box control?

Tags: web-part, rich-text

I basically want to create a web part that will have a rich text box control where CMS users can add the web part to a web part page layout and then edit & save the rich text content within the web part. Is this even possible?

Update: The rich text box content will be html content that our CMS editors can publish on an anonymous access public facing site.
We're hoping the rich text box content would be saved to content columns. We're in a Sharepoint 2013 environment. We would want the Rich Text Box (content placeholder) to be editable in edit mode and then publishable.

Comment: You will need to tell us more... such as, what do you plan to do with the data typed into the rich text box? Where will you be saving it to?

Comment: Thanks @MikeSmith-MCT-MVP . Updated. Let me know if you need more info.